# Removing a div from a view when a certain text appears

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a panel which shows a progress of a certain task with a trace of the log.
I want to change the color of that panel from gray(current) to green when the log prints a certain line.
The log is also present in the view so I could do all this in the view with razor sharp, but how so ? 
This is the view :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="reveal-email" role="button">
<div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert" style="width:50%;margin-left:375px;font-family:'Advent Pro', sans-serif;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <strong> Export processing...</strong><br />

        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3" style="padding-left:300px">
            <label for="reveal-email" class="btn">
                <i class="icon ion-ios-toggle" style="color:rgb(49,52,55);"></i>
                Log
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--   THIS IS THE LOGGING PART  !-->
<div id="email" class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" style="width:50%;margin-left:375px;font-family:'Advent Pro', sans-serif;">
    <p> Log Started at @DateTime.Now </p>
    <ul style="color:#222;font-style:oblique" id="messagesList"></ul>
</div>
```

Basically the ul in the logging div appends the log each time the server detects a new line (in the backend)...One of the lines is :
 ***Log : 
Job "TN_LR_DEV1"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_05" successfully completed at Sun May 10 17:58:24 2020 elapsed 0 00:01:23*** 
Which basically means that the task is completed..only then I want to remove the first div (panel) and add another panel below everything with a green color(or show it if it's marked as hidden)

Comment: Can you control the extension/js function which adding the log to `messagesList` div ?

Comment: Yes the javascript part is basically a signalr hub that appends to the <ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with checking if a certain string exists in the new log line appended to the view, if boolean is true then :
`document.getElementById("succ").style.display = "block";`
with succ being the panel showing a success message and by default its display is set to none.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to hide/show the element . For example , you can add another div and set background to green :

```
<div id="completedDiv"  style="display:none;background:aquamarine;">

</div>
```

And in your js function that getting log from server side , you can check the log and show/hide related div using JQuery/Javascript :

```
let log = 'Log : Job "TN_LR_DEV1"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_05" successfully completed at Sun May 10 17:58:24 2020 elapsed 0 00:01:23';

if (log.indexOf("successfully completed") >= 0) {

    $("#completedDiv").show();
}
```

Comment: I've tried it on the hub javascript and nothing changes on the view,i even tried with getElementById.style.display="block" and still doesn't change anything

Comment: I can post the full javascript and the view if you want on github